# Is it possible to call a prefab in Unity using a variable?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm making an App that instantiates a certain model when the camera is pointed to a QR.

The app then comunicates to a website and shows the data of a place related to the model (example: botanic garden, it shows some flowers and a text about ecology)

Thing is, while I can use text from a website using JSon, I can't seem to find a way to do the same.

I also have a code that makes a JSon, this one returns the name of the model.

My question is, is there a way to use that name to search the prefab in my assets and thus instantiate the prefab?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible, create a dictionary (string, GameObject) and a list for the inspector with its prefabs, use the list to create a new dictionary

Private void Awake(){
dictionary = new Dictionary (string,GameObject); // <- (don't use parentheses) 
foreach ( GameObject go in yourList ) {
dictionary.Add(go, go.name);

}

Private void Search(string name){
if(dictionary.ContainsKey ( name )){

Instantiate(dictionary[name]);

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Workaround, assign prefabs in editor, in your script have references to different prefabs:

```
public GameObject prefab1;
public GameObject prefab2;
```

When you want to instantiate your prefab

```
switch (JSONstring) {

case "Garden":
Instantiate(prefab1, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
break;

}
```

Comment: So, should I make a apublic gameobject and a case for each prefab I have? (aka, garden, street, office, lake, lab)

Comment: Yes, then you can just dunk in your prefab in the inspector and your script has a reference to it